# Peintures/Tableaux - pourquoi utilise-t-on le masculin même si le sujet est féminin?

Tags: usage, articles, genre

J'ai trois examples qui démontrent la raison derrière ma question:

- l'artiste Tamara de Lempicka a créé l'oeuvre "[Nu adossé I](https://www.wikiart.org/en/tamara-de-lempicka/reclining-nude-i-1925)"
- Modigliani a également créé "[Nu couché (sur le côté gauche)](https://www.irishtimes.com/culture/art-and-design/john-magnier-s-modigliani-fetches-157-2m-at-sotheby-s-1.3495715)"
- Degas, de même "[Nu assis de dos](http://www.artmag.com/museums/a_suisse/aswgepp2.html)"

Vous remarquerez que les noms des oeuvres décrivent des sujets qui sont (ou pourraient être) masculins ("Nu") bien que les tableaux soient clairement des images de femme.

J'aimerais savoir **pourquoi** utilise-t-on le mot "Nu" quand il s'agit de femmes - est-ce bien une pratique courante pour les oeuvres artistiques (pense-t-on par example au "nu" en general).

Y a-t-il d'autres examples de ce genre de phenomène et, si oui, quand?

J'apprécierai des références quelconques (URL &c...).

(n.b. Quoique les deux premiers artistes ne soient pas français, ils ont passé la (vaste) majorité de leur(s) vie(s)/carrière(s) en France)

Comment: Je ne suis pas sur mais je crois qu'en peinture un "nu" désigne un type de peinture dans lequel le modèle est une personne nue. Il est donc probable que le titre se rapporte au "type" de peinture plutôt qu'au modèle lui même.

Comment: J'avais cette idée moi-même - mais, j'aimerais une référence quelconque. Toutefois merci, je vais édité ma question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme l'indique @TimLepage, parce que *nu* ici désigne le type du tableau et est indépendant du sujet au même titre que *nature morte* ou *fresque* le sont.

[Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé, définition II. B. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/nu)

> P. méton. OEuvre représentant un nu. Faire un nu; un nu d'Ingres. Mademoiselle Sara Keller, la propre fille du peintre illustre, aurait posé pour ce «nu glorieux» que tout le monde admire au Salon (Gide, Geneviève, 1936, p.1376).

Comment: True, but there's still some tension between the definition and the normal usage: it's not the œuvre that's leaning back or lying down or seated, but the figure. I'm tempted to wonder if *nu* is also simply a masculine noun meaning "a nude figure" regardless of the gender of the figure, the same way *personne* is feminine regardless of the gender of the person... Though I can't definitely identify such a usage in the TLFi.